# SQL ignoring WHERE when searching different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, sql-like

I have an SQL query that is ignoring parts of the WHERE function.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM table
WHERE col1 = 'yes'
AND col2 = 'no'
AND col3 || col4
LIKE '%maybe%'
```

Without the last `AND` function it brings back the correct rows, but with the LIKE function it will bring back rows with 'no' in `col1`.

Comment: What DBMS is this, MySQL?

Comment: phpMyAdmion is not a DBMS, just a front-end for something else (typically MySQL)

Comment: I'm trying to pull out info info where col1 doesn't have no. If there's another way to do it I'd be happy with that too.

Comment: Try putting brackets around to make sure that the Ands and Ors are in the correct place.

Comment: Ah right yeah, looking at the Database server it says Software: MySQL

Comment: That did it! adding '' to 'col3' || 'col4' fixed it!

Comment: Eh? I don't think so. The problem is that without parentheses MySQL misinterprets your 'OR' as 'AND (col3 = col3) OR (col4 LIKE '%maybe%')

Comment: Whatever the issue was, putting the '' gave the impression it worked correctly, but with a bit more time I realised it actually hadn't. The answer given by MikeB actually sorted out what I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to make a guess that you intend that `LIKE` statement to distribute - in which case you want :

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM table
WHERE col1 = 'yes'
AND col2 = 'no'
AND (col3 LIKE '%maybe%'  OR col4 LIKE '%maybe%')
```

Comment: That's excellent, took me a little while to implement it onto the site and check it but works now. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate `col3` and `col4`, the right syntax in mysql is to use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT
  col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM
  table
WHERE
  col1 = 'yes'
  AND col2 = 'no'
  AND CONCAT(col3, col4) LIKE '%maybe%'
```

while || is the OR operator.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4e18/1).

Comment: The SQL dialect could vary. Oracle uses a '||' operator for string concatenation.

Comment: @Pekka in oracle || is the operator for string concatenation, i thought that the OP was trying to convert the oracle syntax to mysql, but he was looking for an OR instead